# How to remove the element from the json structure without its values by javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, xml

This is the structure that i am having, i converted from the xml to json, but now i dont need the root element and also the ***element*** tag:

```
{
"root": {
    "batchRequests": [
        {
            "element": {
                "method": "PATCH",
                "url": "url",
                "richInput": {
                    "Error_Message__c": {},
                    "Status__c": "0"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "element": {
                "method": "PATCH",
                "url": "url",
                "richInput": {
                    "Error_Message__c": {},
                    "Status__c": "0"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to transform that into this structure:

```
{
"batchRequests": [
    {
        "method": "PATCH",
        "url": "url",
        "richInput": {
            "Error_Message__c": "",
            "Status__c": "0"
        }
    },
    {
        "method": "PATCH",
        "url": "url",
        "richInput": {
            "Error_Message__c": "",
            "Status__c": "1"
        }
    }
]
}
```

Can you please help me with this transformation, if it is possible from javascript?

Comment: You can also iterate and assign like json = json.root, etc. but a bit than declarative way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with this single line.

```
 yourObject = { batchRequests: yourObject.root.batchRequests.map((x) => x.element) }
```

Try it here.

```js
var yourObject = {
  "root": {
    "batchRequests": [{
        "element": {
          "method": "PATCH",
          "url": "url",
          "richInput": {
            "Error_Message__c": {},
            "Status__c": "0"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "element": {
          "method": "PATCH",
          "url": "url",
          "richInput": {
            "Error_Message__c": {},
            "Status__c": "0"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

yourObject = { batchRequests: yourObject.root.batchRequests.map((x) => x.element) }

console.log(yourObject);
```

Comment: @MayurTripathi Welcome. If this answer worked for you maybe you could mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Also, how can i iterate now in this new varaible:
based on status_code, i want to update the counter.

Comment: @MayurTripathi I didn't understand your question, you can iterate and access the status_code like so. `yourObject.batchRequests.forEach((x) => console.log(x.richInput.Status__c))`  Is this what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

If your json item is called `json`:

```
let result = {batchRequests:[]};
for(let item of json.root.batchRequests){
    result.batchRequests.push(item.element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Parse `batchRequests` with `map` function:

   `const batchRequests = data1.root.batchRequests.map(el => el.element)`
2. Create new object with this data:

   `const data2 = { batchRequests }`

```js
const data1 = {
  "root": {
    "batchRequests": [
        {
            "element": {
                "method": "PATCH",
                "url": "url",
                "richInput": {
                    "Error_Message__c": {},
                    "Status__c": "0"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "element": {
                "method": "PATCH",
                "url": "url",
                "richInput": {
                    "Error_Message__c": {},
                    "Status__c": "0"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
  }
}

const batchRequests = data1.root.batchRequests.map(el => el.element)

const data2 = { batchRequests }
console.log(data2)
```